# Capture 48MP/50MP/100MP images of vivo X60 pro+ with Camera2 API

Tags: android-camera2, android-camerax

I would like to capture the high-resolution image (48MP/50MP/100MP) in vivo X60 Pro+ in a self-developed APP. The high-resolution images come from the rear cameras. The 48MP image is from the Ultra-wide angle camera, and the 50MP/100MP image is from the primary camera. I've tried using Camera2 API Probe. The highest resolution shown there is only 12 MP (4080 x 3060). However, I've also tried Camera2 API and was able to see 4 physical camera ids (2,3,4,5) for the back camera from **CameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics("0").physicalCameraIds**. I wonder if there's a way to access/capture high-resolution images with the Camera2 API. Or is it possible to access those through other lower-level API? Thank you!